# Unable to get Response from spring webservice

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I was implementing an angularJS and spring integration tutorial. Here I want to call Spring controller from my angular js code and store the user details in database.Here I am able to hit the webservice and also able to store the details in database. But I am not receiving any response returned by controller in my js and also in console I can see an error msg which is not clear though.

Error in console

```
angular.js:10573 GET http://localhost:8083/HCP_Android_Demo/user?username=akur&address=hhh&email=xyz@gmail.com&callback=angular.callbacks._
```

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user",method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})    
@ResponseBody
public boolean createUser(@RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("address")String address,@RequestParam("email") String email,@RequestParam("callback")String callBackFunction){
    System.out.println("Creating User " + username);
    boolean insertStatus=userService.save(username,address,email);
    System.out.println("insert status is"+insertStatus);//prints true
    return insertStatus;

}
```

services.js

```
  angular.module('myApp').factory('UserService', ['$http', function($http){
return{
    createUser: function(username,address,email){

        var url="http://localhost:8083/HCP_Android_Demo/user?username="+username+"&address="+address+"&email="+email+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
        return $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
            alert(data);
            return data;
        });
    }
};
 }]);
```

Comment: You have missed the part of the error message.

Comment: what happens if you execute your call? can you show error message from chrome console?

Comment: Maybe you have to url encode the email-address.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan in eclipse console there is no error log. And in google chrome console no http status as error is coming. It is returning just angular.js:10573 GET http://localhost:8083/HCP_Android_Demo/user?username=akur&address=hhh&email=xyz@gmail.com&callback=angular.callbacks._

Comment: I myself found the solution.. I was missing 2 jackson jars..